# Is the a Postfix milter supporting dkim with IDN and UTF8

Tags: postfix, dkim, idn

I use postfix mailserver with enabled SMTPUTF8 and some IDNs, before I used IDNs I used OpenDKIM, but OpenDKIM crashes if I use the IDN in utf8 form. Then I tried pyopendkim. Then I tried dkimpy-milter, but it just does not sign UTF8 mails.

Is there a milter which supports this. I do not need a DKIM verifier just a signer.

Comment: While this does not answer your question, you may try filing a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/dkimpy) with dkimpy. They seem more active than OpenDKIM.

Comment: I've filled it.